# R.java disappears after project clean

Tags: android, eclipse

After I added some .png files into my Project Workspace drawable folder I refreshed my drawable folders in Eclipse and the newly added files showed up. But when I tried to access those resources using R.drawable.xyzimage, xyzimage although in the folder could not be resolved.

So I did a Project Clean and guess what after this clean R.java is totally gone and all my classes accessing resources using R.java is showing all sorts of error and Eclipse won't let me run the code anymore.

I have backup of my source code but I want to explore if R.java can be regenerated and how?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: not only which eclipse version are you using but also what ADT plugin version are you using?

Comment: Eclipse 3.5.2 / Android Dev Toolkit 0.9.8

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try Project->Clean in Eclipse. In my limited experience if R.java is not being automatically created then there is an error somewhere in your xml. Triple check everything.

Comment: This is very true. Also the naming convention should be followed for anything in the res folder  or any other folder for that matter.

Comment: yep somethings up in one of the xml layout files

Comment: some variables are removed from the xml layout. So references in `R.java` were not referenced to any variable in a xml file (could be `layout/activity_main.xml` or `value/string.xml` )

Comment: XML error it was. Every other question was saying clean clean, but the answer is to stop being a twat and fix your xml errors.

Comment: i cannot see any error on my xml files.. how to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

You have to build the project to be able to use the newly added resources.

Cleaning a project removes all auto-generated files. Building the project it should automatically create them. When you Clean a project, there's an option to start a build immediately after clean up.

Here's a few things you can try (did the same procedure after manually deleting the "**gen**" directory.

- After you have deleted the **gen** directory, go to Project > Clean ...
- You should have errors indicating that R cannot be resolved to a variable. Right click on your project from the Package Explorer and select Build Project. Be sure Build Automatically option is turned off (uncheck in Project > Build Automatically).
- Errors regarding R should have now disappeared. Now, perform a Project Clean once again. All errors should be gone.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: deleted gen. built project. the gen folder came back but not R.java

Answer (score 4):

Here is what the problem was. I added those new png images to the project and android has rules as to what characters are allowed in the names of these images. Once I changed the uppercase letters in the image name, it was back on track again and Build Automatically generated the R.java file and all errors were gone. Eclipse console is the place where I found all the errors related to my resources.

Thanks Guys....I tried your solutions but my error was something specific which was due to my image naming convention so this is the way I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree this is usually a XML problem but moreover that it is something within your res folder that is the problem and may be highlighted with a red cross after the clean attempt.

I have just had this problem and it was because I had created my own folder called 'data' within res folder.  After the clean it had a little red cross against it.  I removed this folder and R built again.

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 2):

Several things you should check in your project:

- Check the Problems tab in your Eclipse IDE. Are you sure that you did not introduced building problems while making changes with drawables? To check that you need to check xml source of affected layout and see if something is marked red.
- In File explorer go to the directory where your Android project is. Check that you have file **default.properties** (.classpath, .project and AndroidManifest.xml should be there). If default.properties is missing it may be easily replaced by correct version.
- Which is the Android version you are working with? If that is 1.5 or lower be sure that in the *res* directory you have directory named *drawable*, not *drawable-hdpi*, *drawable-mdpi* and *drawable-ldpi*. Last three are valid for version 1.6 and higher.
- Right click on your project in Package explorer in Eclipse. You will get a number of options. Go to Android Tools-> Fix Project Properties so see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had an invalid jpg in my res/drawable folder. I removed the jpg and it worked.

Comment: Same error on my side! created a copy of an image on my mac and it was in that folder as "image copy.png". Spent almost an hour trying to find it!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on my Mac too and I think it could be good to know for all Mac users how I managed to solve this error.

I had a .DSStore file automatically imported to my project inside the res directory and when I removed it and rebuilt the project all went well.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you clean the project and it rebuilds, it imports

> import.android.R

so, delete this import and remove all errors from xml files. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me if I move my project to a new location.  I have found that the answers above didn't fix my problem, but that creating a new project and importing the source did.

Answer (score 1):

This may be simple but check to make sure you don't use

import android.R;

Answer (score 1):

If you add an external resource file with capital letters for example
"Hello.png or WelcomeSound.mp3 etc etc" like if you add upper case letters and clean your project you'd surely loose your R.java file. So if you already lost it, either rename the file externally and then clean your project or else right click on the project Refractor->Rename and then rename your file with all letters in lower casing. Next, delete the 'gen' folder in the project explorer and now right click and "Build Project". If Build Project option is grayed out, go to Project-> Deselect "Build Automatically" option.

Regards,

Kshitij Thube

Answer (score 1):

Check at the **Console View** If there in message Error, It will Help you to find out the source of the probleme.
I had i similar probleme and i find out that the probleme was from the pic name even if the name respect the Syntax so I change it  to img1 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing one line of code in your project, then build the project once more.

Comment: how do i build? if you give me the eclipse navigation that would be great. thanks

Comment: I just tried Project -> Build and Build All. These options were not active since I had Build Automatically checked. But it did not fix the R.java problem

Answer (score 0):

Another thing: never try to run an application with the texteditor opened with a xml file. That will create a wierd run configuration that can only be fixed by project clean-up and sometimes can make the xml file to vanish (happened to me twice already).

Answer (score 0):

Check your file in drawable folder ensure that all are resource file (image) remove unwanted file Like **thumb.db**. Remove those all files and check again

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem after lots of cleaning and building project again and again. I found that on console there is this error:

```
res/drawable-hdpi/Blue Blank.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

and this is not appearing as an error in xml. I changed the name and save the file, clean project and build. Now it's working. My suggestion check your res folder and name of files you use in it and name only `[a-z0-9_.]`.

Delete related tag in xml, save xml, clean project, build project. Now again put that resource in xml and save!

Answer (score 0):

All my `R.*` files stopped working after I did a `Project->clean` in Eclipse. The issue was that I backed up a `XML` file attached to one of my activities in the layout directory. This causes errors in every activity of my project.

After deleting the file I still had `R` errors in one of my `Activities` and it only was resolved after I tried importing different files and then deleting them. I actually made no change to the previous imports but for some reason deleting them all and re-pasting them fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your png files have lowercase names.  That is what kept throwing mine out, because I capitalized the first letter, or I used an unallowed non alpha numeric in the naming.  Check that before destroying any of your code.

Comment: All res files should only contain these characters [a-z0-9_.]

Answer (score 0):

just check your image folder (usually created res > drawable files) and be sure dont use capital letters on .png files, every type must be in small letters then you can find again your R.java under the gen file folder

Answer (score 0):

i removed 'import android.R;' then commented out the offending lines, then did a build, ok

then i removed the comment and it fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I cleaned my project. I got crazy to solve it, I searched and searched but solved it in my way. 
First of all, **delete all needless files in your /res folder**. I had some notes in it, I took them to another project that I don't work on it and build the project manually. It worked! Try this I'm sure it will help.

**Good developing!**

Answer (score 0):

Was there an XML file with the naming convention of "somthing.out.xml" generated?  If so you should delete this file (an unwanted file of this name can cause major problems for your somthing.somthing.R file import).

In some versions of eclipse (I know eclipse javaEE does this for sure), running the project while viewing an XML file will create a file called filename.out.xml in your res->layout folder.  You must delete this generated file if this has occurred otherwise you wont be able to get the java.R file to import.

Answer (score 0):

Try Project -> check Build Automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 64-bit Ubuntu, try to install the 32-bit libraries (ia32-libs)

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This exact same thing happened to me. coincidentally I needed to update my adk that day, so i did so and after restarting eclipse it worked again. My recommendation would be to build the project and restart eclipse. It is not due to any error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I read and tried many of the above after simply doing a clean on one project. Eclipse would not build anything afterwards.

Fortunately I had last-nights backup of the workspace and my source is copied in from VS 2010.

No more cleaning!

Answer (score 0):

Delete your project from workspace witout source deleting and then import it into workspace.

RightClick on your Project -> Delete /Don't select "Delete project content on disk (cannot be undone)"/ ->  Ok

File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> Brouse -> /Look for your workspace(!) folder/ -> Ok -> /your cleaned project will be automatically checked/ -> Finish

Answer (score 0):

I had the dreaded ***missing R*** problem yesterday with Eclipse Juno after a routine clean.  StackExchange is full of suggestions and extensive googling revealed only the usual suspects (XML naming conventions problems, etc) none of which seemed to apply directly, although it is certainly possible I missed something.

The best summary comprehensive list of possible causes and fixes was here:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-comprehensive-troubleshooting-guide-for-androids-r-cannot-be-resolved-error/

One useful tip there was to try to create and run a simple "**Hello World**" in my workspace.   If that does not run, the setup is corrupted.  My Hello World was just as full of errors as my custom app.

The solution that worked for me (perhaps great overkill but nothing else worked) was to completely uninstall Android SDK and delete Eclipse (Juno), download Eclipse for Developers (Kepler) and reinstall Android ADT plugin and ADK and recreated my AVDs using the latest "compile with" version in options.

So far so good, although I am recreating the app from scratch.   I will be more cautious about using clean from here on.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem occur just now I renamed invalid png file like **demo.1.png  as demo.png ** and its work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these kind of error occured by size vary in mdpi and xhdpi.so you have to check your image size for both mdpi and xhdpi.Otherwise check the Naming Convention.

Answer (score 0):

Proven successful method, check the file (AndroidManifest.xml) and delete all comments in it, and make sure there are no errors in this file, I tried and did work with me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but after i deleted the custom menuitem.xml created, I was able to regenerate R.java file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my English is bad. I had a similar problem, after making a cleaning project R.java file would disappear. But erased the GEN directory and build the project again this file is not recreated. Ok, so a comment on the name of the images I had and I realized that one of the images is GIF extension. In my project, my target is 4.1 and is 2.2 min. The solution that worked me was:
1) Delete the GIF image
2) Delete the directory GEN
3) Right click on the project select Build Project.
I hope someone will work.

Answer (score 0):

first: Uncheck menu > project >build automaticaly.

Second; Menu > project > clean > select your project, then check the option "build only the selected projects".

Press ok button.

then R.java file was build successfully again by Eclipse.