# When I clean project in android using clean option, R.java is removed from gen file

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R.java disappears after project clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896301/r-java-disappears-after-project-clean)

I am using "Eclipse Indigo" editor. In my android project when I use clean option tool to clean errors present in project then "R.java" present in gen folder is also deleted. I turned ON and OFF eclipse for couple of times,but R.java file is not found in project.

Please help me. Helping hands are highly appreciated.

Comment: Go to `Project - Build project`. The R.java should be generated then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896301/r-java-disappears-after-project-clean

Comment: I tried to "project Build project" but R.java is not generated

Answer (score 3):

Possible problem is, In your layouts you got any error, but eclipse isn't pointing it out that error. Please see problems tab near to console if you got any error. And consider going through from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating) post to know more about why R.java sometimes not generated by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. The clean process deletes gen and bin files, to be rebuild. Once your project has been cleaned up, they should appear again, unless you have any error in your res files, in which case, the R.java will be unable to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

If the R file is not regenerated during the clean process, this is because your project has some errors (other than the ones generated by the missing R file). Check your project and fix the other errors.

I think you have errors in your XML files - the R.java is generated from xml attributes. Review your code and fix the errors.