# R.java doesn't save Id in Android

Tags: java, android, string

I'm developing a new project where I'm using some code from other project.

Yesterday, I copied the files I needed from the other project to the new one. But I saw that it didn't recognize some `textview's and seekbar's IDs`. So I do make clean to the project and the `R.java file` disappeared.

I've read that is something that happens to many people but I don't know how to solve.

Today, I've started a new project, and instead of copying the old files, I've created new ones and pasted the code that I only need. But the problem continues. In the java files, it doesn't recognize the layout object's IDs.

Whats the reason why this happens and how can i solve it??

Comment: Post your xml's which causes problem..

Comment: All the XML that I have cause this problem. The thing is that I know that those XML work fine in other project.

Comment: In your xml files have problem check all the xml's properly and then clean the app.. it will work.

Comment: Done it. The R.java file has dissapeared again.

Comment: If you imported `import android.R;` than remove it...

Comment: Do you have any errors highlighted in your res folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [R.java disappears after project clean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896301/r-java-disappears-after-project-clean)

Comment: No errors in the res folder.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** go to `project` in `file menu` of `eclipse` than **click on** `Build Automatically`, **if its not showing tick Symbol** !

**2.** if you have `import android.R;` **than remove it** it should be of `import your_package_name.R;`

Comment: No, I think that when you copy a part of code from other project, the R is imported from that porject. If you save the new one having this import on your file, the R.java file dissapears. If started a new project.

Comment: @masmic_87 you will have to delete that import also !

Comment: Started a new Project. Everything ok until now. I've created some layout whithout warnings but in the java file, it appears like it isn't created: " X cannot be resolved or is not a fied".

Comment: go to project in file menu and check build automatically is ticked or not ?

Comment: Yes, is ticked. If done all the things that are said to do: Cleaning, fixing, I don't know what more to do...

Comment: I understand that for first declare an Id, @+id is used. I use @+id. The thing is that I've developed 2 parts of the app independetly. And now i need to join booth and continue developing. The problem is that when I copy the files into the new project, the new layouts don't save the Ids in the R.java, so the java files don't find no the layout neither the objects.

Comment: why did you not mentioned this earlier ? than you will have to manually import the R in your project with package name in new xml files ! like import yourpackagename.R; for all new xmls which are to be used !

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to import any package. I'm creating a new project taking parts of code from the other projects. I get to a piont where it doesn't let me to run the project, is says that the project has errors, but I don't see any file whith errors.

Comment: SOLVED! I was copying the strings from the other project to the new one. When creating one by one new ones for the new project, no problems are created. Thanks for your help.