# Eclipse built & clean always lose R-file

Tags: android, eclipse

When I clean and build my project,my project always looses the R.java file. I updated my build tool. I tried to build my project again but it still does not work. What could be a problem. I do not want to always create new project. Should I delete something from .metadata folder?

Comment: Could be a syntax error in one of the xml resource files.

Comment: Why is everyone repeating Henry answer it corect thank you Henry..

Answer (score 0):

has been already answered here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3897986/2074990

aswell there can be a problem with the v22 sdk. there are lots of fixes for this purpose too.

Answer (score 0):

You can have errors in your resource files (layouts, drawables, values, etc).