# R.java was deleted after cleaning the project

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I accidently deleted my `R.java` after cleaning the project (Project->Clean). Is there any way to restore or re-create the file?

I tried to build the project but `R.java` still missing from the project.

Comment: Just build your project once.

Comment: Go to project and checked Build Automatically,it will solve your problem.

Comment: @avijit You mean run the project? If so, I tried and failed bacause of lack R.java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R.java disappears after project clean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896301/r-java-disappears-after-project-clean)

Comment: @Nizam This isn't duplicate, I saw this question and his answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a the things I ahve tried.

- Rebuilding the project (failed)
- Manually creating `R.java` and wait until the adt will generate the content (failed)
- Did `Project->clean` another time (failed)
- Deleted the gen folder and waited until adt will re-create it (failed)

The answer:

- **Created new project and copied the files that not auto generated (succeeded)**

Answer (score 2):

You have to build the project to be able to use the newly added resources.

Cleaning a project removes all auto-generated files. Building the project it should automatically create them. When you Clean a project, there's an option to start a build immediately after clean up.

Here's a few things you can try (did the same procedure after manually deleting the "gen" directory.

- After you have deleted the gen directory, go to Project > Clean ...
- You should have errors indicating that R cannot be resolved to a variable. Right click on your project from the Package Explorer and select Build Project. Be sure Build Automatically option is turned off (uncheck in Project > Build Automatically).
- Errors regarding R should have now disappeared. Now, perform a Project Clean once again. All errors should be gone.

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

*Build* the project again an do not worry, `R.java` is generated each time the project is built

Comment: Are you sure the build succeeded? If there is an error in XML files or your source code it won't

Comment: Yes I'm sure that the build succeeded.

Comment: still the same problem? well then you may have invalid resources or something, anything else that prevents build without feedback. Consider double checking everything or starting a new clone project to copy into part by part trying to see what exactly the issue is

Answer (score 0):

I will automatically create by eclipse no need to create by us. just build the project i.e save the changes will automatically build it for u.

Comment: So there is problem in adt because R.java wasnt created.

Answer (score 0):

R.java file is automatically created when you build the workspace, so it should be generated again with the next cleaning of project, unless you have errors in java or xml files, so check if you have errors in your project and correct them first.

Comment: So there is problem in adt because R.java wasnt created.

Comment: did you refresh the project after the build? perhaps there is a problem with adt, and you can try building from the command line with ant clean: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Answer (score 0):

In the eclipse you have down to the clean project you have option **Build Automatically** try to enable it....

Comment: I enabled the **Build Automatically**, rebuilded bur R.java still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just **Restart** the Eclipse will solve this Issue as the workspace will be freshly Build  ! go to

**File -> Restart**

Try this method by first right click on ur project folder -> **Close Unrelated Projects**!

Its the fastest way to avoid frustration by going it into Build,preferencen,properties,blah blah.....

Moreover, this technique always works when the R.java file is deleted and not restored back immediately !

Evenafter the problem persists then make a new project and add copy ur xml and java files to that project , delete the previous one . . . .

Comment: I tried to build the project and restarting adt but R.jqva still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just click Project > Build Project

When you build the project, you don't get R.java.
You should check external library. Just remove the external library and add external library.

Android projects get tangled easily.

Comment: Did you mean *remove the external libraries and add them again*? And what do you mean you don't get `R.java` when you build the project?

Comment: I tried to build the project and restarting adt but R.jqva still missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: building the project, the R.java file was missing. I built the project, but there were errors in the resource XML file. Correct them, then rebuild. When there were no errors anymore, the R.java was recreated and contained all the R.id.xxx items I had inserted in the resource.

Answer (score 0):

This recently happened to me (10 mins ago) for my Android project, and my **solution** was a mix of things I read in some answers here.

What I did to fix was:

- revert to **older version** (I used Github)
- R.java still missing so I **deleted** "gen" and "bin" folders
- R.java was generated and errors **disapeared**

This was done using Eclipse Luna. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

[Gradle Project Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoP1h.png)

I tried clicking all the stuff under Gradle Projects tab, and noticed a few small errors, example: I had a capital letter in the drawable folder. I ran anything that had to do with processing or updating or generating resources. final one I did was "processDebugResources"

[missing R folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nNkQ.png)

I had also noticed the folder circled in the above image was missing, running "processDebugResources" seemed to have regenerated the folder, although the others I clicked under the Gradle Projects tab could have also helped